# MODx template variable is link to an image jpg but doesnt show

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I have a template variable in MODx EVO and its called `image-link`.
The URL of the images are something like... http://www.friendssite-image5.jpg.

In my HTML I have this:

```html
[[if? &is=`[+image-link+]:not_empty` &then=` 
<div class="image-link">
<a href="[~[+id+]~]"><img alt="[*longtitle*]" src=
"[+image-link+]"></a>
        </div>`]]
```

I tried setting the template variable as `URL` , also as `image`, and also as `text`, but the image does not want to appear. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that you have your tags mixed between [+...+] and [*...*]. The "+" signs are for use with Ditto, but if you are placing the call directly in your document, use the "*" signs instead.

Example

Change:

```
[[if? &is=`[+image-link+]:not_empty` &then=` 
<div class="image-link">
<a href="[~[+id+]~]"><img alt="[*longtitle*]" src=
"[+image-link+]"></a>
    </div>`]]
```

To:

```
[[if? &is=`[*image-link*]:not_empty` &then=` 
<div class="image-link">
<a href="[~[*id*]~]"><img alt="[*longtitle*]" src=
"[*image-link*]"></a>
    </div>`]]
```